# Disabling all schedules in Glassfish 3.1

Tags: glassfish-3, ejb-3.1, schedule

How can I disable all schedulers (@Schedule annotated) in a project deploing on Glassfish 3.1
 Maybe there are some config entries to do this?
 I have about 20 EJBs with schedulers in my project and if I want to test/fix a small thing I don't want that all/some timer start.

Comment: Wasn't the `@Schedule` annotation added in the EJB 3.1 (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html#persistent%28%29)? Are you using EJB 3.1 or 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately I don't know if there are some config entries to solve your problem, but there is a programatical way to do so, by calling the *cancel()*-method on **Timer**-Objects provided by **TimerService**.

Here's an example of a class I simply put into projects when I want to test only small things:

```
@Stateless
public class ScheduleCancellation {

  @Resource
  private TimerService timerService;

  @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "*", hour = "*")
  public void cancelTimers() {
    System.out.println("cancelTimers()");
    for (Timer timer : timerService.getTimers()) {
      System.out.println("schedule gone!");
      timer.cancel();
    }
  }

  @Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "*")
  public void tick() {
    System.out.println("tick");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The getTimer() method returns only the active timers associated with this bean. Maybe is it possible to get all timers in the project and deactivate these?

Answer (score 2):

Accessing `TimerService#getTimers()` will only return timers for this particular EJB. There is no standardized way to access all the timers in the container (actually, here is an enhancement request: http://java.net/jira/browse/EJB_SPEC-47).

I guess you'd need to use some Glassfish proprietary solution and fiddle with their internals (if it's even possible). I'd ask on [GlassFish mailing list](http://glassfish.java.net/public/mailing-lists.html) if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. I'll ask the mailing list.

Comment: Here is the answer from Glassfish mail group:  http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/disabling-all-schedules-glassfish-31